# Truffle migrate:The method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available

Tags: truffle, rinkeby

I have both my local geth node and geth console running in the background.

geth console command :

`geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi = "personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "~/Library/Ethereum/geth.ipc"`

local geth node command :

```
geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

which allows me to connect to the geth console

```
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.8.3-stable-329ac18e/windows-amd64/go1.10
coinbase: 0xc496398f167316e763523503b9d7cedd7f47d0a4
at block: 0 (Wed, 12 Apr 2017 22:59:06 +08)
 datadir: C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\rinkeby
 modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

However, when I run `truffle migrate --reset --compile-all --network rinkeby`

I get this error saying that :

```
Error: The method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:1)
    at C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:86:1
    at C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:1)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

**truffle-config.js**

```
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: "localhost", // Connect to geth on the specified
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "4",
      gas: 4612388 // Gas limit used for deploys
    }
  }
};
```

I'm following the steps in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rumMSlrmiI&t=892s
My suspect is something to do with webpack or truffle. But i have added both packages.

Comment: I think your command line have a wrong =, try with `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi "personal,eth,network,web3,net"`. The extra ipcpath is not necessary on windows.